# Return true if any element of array is equal to n or sum of two elements of array is equal to n - improve performance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As in title I want to return true if any element of array is equal to n or sum of two elements of array is equal to n. So if array is [1,4,5] and n is 1 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 9 I want to get true. Here's my code:

```
function checkArray (x, array) {
  return array.includes(x) || array.some((item, i) => array.slice(i+1).includes(x-item)); 
}
```

It works fine but is using "some" the best way in terms of performance? How can I improve execution speed?

Edit: Negative numbers are allowed

Comment: Before doing `some` you could filter out any single array item that's greater the sum. I don't know if your input array is guaranteed to be sorted or not, or how many items long it could be. I guess this would also assume that there's no negative numbers.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Negative numbers are allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `some` other than the normal performance overhead of allocating/garbage collecting a function object and spinning up a function call for each and every element of the array.

It's pretty much always fastest to use a traditional `for` loop, but this is generally a micro-optimization that should only be used as a last resort -- refactoring from idiomatic high-level callback-driven JS code to `for` loop only offers a constant factor speedup.

Before resorting to that, I'd recommend lowering your time complexity: `Array#includes` is O(n), as is `Array#slice`. Doing these operations in a nested loop is O(n^2).

You can try the classic "space vs time" tradeoff and use a set to store each element you've seen so far. If `n - currentElement === something in the set`, you've located two numbers that sum to `n`.

```js
const oneOrTwoElementsEqualN = (arr, n) => {
  const seen = new Set();
  return arr.some(e => {
    if (e === n || seen.has(n - e)) {
      return true;
    }
    
    seen.add(e);
  });
};

console.log(oneOrTwoElementsEqualN([1,2,3], 5));
console.log(oneOrTwoElementsEqualN([1,2,3], 2));
console.log(oneOrTwoElementsEqualN([1,2,3], 6));
```

Note that this a slight variant of the ["two sum"](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) problem.

Comment: You say it's a space vs time tradeoff, but the space used here is only O(n), and you can't do any better than that because that's how big the input data is. You just get a constant factor on the memory usage.

Comment: No, the space complexity isn't a measurement of the already-allocated input size, it's a measurement of the _algorithm's_ additional space usage. The memory the input takes is purely in the caller. For example, printing an array isn't O(n) space, it's O(1) space because all of the memory for the array belongs to the caller and no new allocations of size n occur. Technically, OP's original algorithm is O(n) space too because `.slice()` copies the whole array, but it's not really essential to their approach, whereas the set here is.